What does the community like to see with posts answering a tangential question, but not the one submitted by the asker?
https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29794/107
This answer has been flagged as not being an answer to the question, and it isn't. But as always on this site, it's a record of first-hand experience that's tangentially related to the question and very much likely to be of interest to anyone reading the question and answers in the first place. Feels like a shame to delete it, perhaps making it a community wiki as a way to distinguish it from the others? I know that's not the original intent of wiki answers but as I said, deleting it feels like a loss.

The post critiqued by the one linked here is hardly an answer to the asker’s question either.

It's a flaw at SO that there isn't a better way to do this kind of thing.   But we do it frequently at this stack, part of the local consensus I've always assumed, and we should continue to allow it.  (And this particular answer is highly interesting and relevant to the people who post on this Stack.)

This is an answer to a question, if not the one it was posted under. Ideally, we should be able to ask that question, and then re-parent the answer to that question. Unfortunately, moderators don't have an answer move tool, so we'll have to ask a friendly CM for help every time if we go this route.
I'm not sure whether the question for this answer would be on-topic, so I've asked that separately.

'Putting the answer up for adoption' was the fairly obvious solution that occurred to me. Do CMs have the power to cause procedural changes that are beneficial to the community (in this context, make an answer-move tool available), or do we just have to shut up and provide marketable content?

@dave Yes, they do, but we're not the only site, and the backlog for tooling is quite long. (Ever since people started moaning about "availability on the non-English sites" and "not taking the entire network down", adding features has become a bit of an involved process.) I think we should prototype a process with asking the CMs to do it manually, before we seriously pursue extra tooling: it might turn out that this doesn't work at all, and then that'd be a load of development effort that could've been better spent on fixing comments or something.

I find the probability of getting some procedure automated is proportional to the number of times manual intervention is requested :-)

Seems like a good approach to me. Create the new question then ask a CM to move the answer accordingly. Does seem like the best option available as it keeps the original question in the format the network wants, while giving us a way to avoid removal of interesting content.
